# The method spark.catalog.tableExists("newDb.newTable") throws NoSuchDatabaseException instead of returning false ("newDb" does not exist)

Tags: database, scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a block of code that checks if a given hive "database.table" exists in the current spark session.

```
val tableExists = spark.catalog.tableExists("newDb.newTable")
```

I want to store the result in a boolean, so, if the table or the **database** don't exist, i want to get **false**.

I run the exact same code on a different environment and it worked just fine, but now I am running it with Scalatest and getting **NoSuchDatabaseException** thrown when the database (in this case "newDb") doesn't exist.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that hive support was not enabled in the default SparkSession provided by the [DataframeSuiteBase class (from Holdenkarau's spark-testing-base package)](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/master/core/src/main/2.0/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/DataFrameSuiteBase.scala) that I was extending.

To solve it, override the DataframeSuiteBase method **beforeAll()** (runs before every test) by adding the **enableHiveSupport()** method to the SparkSession build chain:

```
override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
  SparkSessionProvider._sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local") // add whatever other configurations...
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
spark.catalog._jcatalog.tableExists("schema_name.table_name")
```